# How to manipulate the location of desktop files or folders on a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, macos, desktop

Is there a way to programmatically move a desktop folder or file on the desktop of a Mac to another location on the desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the objective-c APIs (I think you want the [Scripting bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/Concepts/scripting_bridge.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006467-SW1)?), but here's the AppleScript version:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop position of someFile to {50,50}
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NSFileManager.

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager moveItemAtURL:oldURL toURL:newURL error:error];
```

Be sure to correctly handle the error.

Comment: I actually want to move the file from one location of the desktop to another location on the desktop.